# Casting a C++ long type to a JNI jlong

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I am using JNI to pass data between C++ and Java. I need to pass a 'long' type, and am doing so using something like:

```
 long myLongVal = 100;
 jlong val = (jlong)myLongVal;
 CallStaticVoidMethod(myClass, "(J)V", (jvalue*)val);
```

However in Java, when the 'long' parameter is retrieved, it gets retrieved as some very large negative number. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Curiously, Java kept getting 4294967297 when I passed it a value of "1" through JNI. That number is a Fermat number. It seems an awfully coincidental value. If anyone has any ideas as to why this particular value was seen, I'd be interested in hearing it. Back on topic, casting my long as `(jlong) value` allowed Java/JNI to parse it to the correct value of 1.

Comment: 4294967297 is (1 << 32) + 1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you pass a jlong (which is 64 bit) as a pointer (which is, most likely, 32-bit) you necessarily lose data. I'm not sure what's the convention, but try either this:

```
CallStaticVoidMethodA(myClass, "(J)V", (jvalue*)&val); //Note address-of!
```

or this:

```
CallStaticVoidMethod(myClass, "(J)V", val);
```

It's `...A` methods that take a jvalue array, the no-postfix methods take C equivalents to scalar Java types.

The first snippet is somewhat unsafe; a better, if more verbose, alternative would be:

```
jvalue jv;
jv.j = val;
CallStaticVoidMethodA(myClass, "(J)V", &jv);
```

On some exotic CPU archtectures, the alignment requirements for `jlong` variables and `jvalue` unions might be different. When you declare a union explicitly, the compiler takes care of that.

Also note that C++ `long` datatype is often 32-bit. jlong is 64 bits, on 32-bit platforms the nonstandard C equivalent is `long long` or `__int64`.

Comment: "C++ long is 32-bit too"--true on some architectures, not on others.  x64 linux usually uses 64-bit long.  long long isn't available everywhere either (it's an extension IIRC).

Comment: True, that. I'll add a qualification.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - unfortunately I've tried both suggseted approaches and the parameter still appears garbled when retrieved in Java, I also tried with int and float types in addition to long :( Strangely the following *does* work, and only for int types (though it doesn't make sense)
`int someInt = 100;
CallStaticVoidMethod(myClass, "(I)V", (jvalue*)(jint)someInt );`

Comment: DOH! It turns out I was not using `CallStaticVoidMethodA`, but `CallStaticVoidMethod`. Appending the 'A' solves the problem. Thank-you!

Answer (score 4):

```
CallStaticVoidMethod(myClass, "(J)V", (jvalue*)val);
```

This is undefined behaviour. You are casting an integer to be a pointer. It is not a pointer. You need, at the very least, to pass the *address*. This code would on most platforms instantly crash.

Comment: you're absolutely right - I should be taking the address, however this still does not work for me (regardless of float, int or long type, as I tried all of these). Strangely, the following works, and only for int types (though it doesn't make any sense) `int someInt = 100; CallStaticVoidMethod(myClass, "(I)V", (jvalue*)(jint)someInt );`